# Regarding Magnetic coupled circuit

Tags: inductor, transient, coupling, mutual-inductance

Here, all the initial conditions are : i1(0-)=0A and i2(0-)=0A
When t≥0, the current i1(t) and i2(t) starts flowing. From my assumption, steady state value of i1(t) is 10A but what happens to i2(t)? Applying KVL,
10=i1(t)+di1(t)/dt - di2(t)/dt
And i2(t)= di1(t)/dt-di2(t)/dt.
The time constant τ of this Circuit is 2 sec. If at steady state di1(t)/dt =0 then di2(t)/dt=0;then i2(∞)=0A. According to my calculation,
i1(t)=10-10e^(-0.5t) but what about i2(t)?How to figure out the i2(t) equation? Is it all zero? Please help me out with i2(t)?
[image]
I simulated the circuit and got these for 60Hz...
[image]
[image]
[image]
Both of them are same in simulation graph. How is it possible? Also this circuit can not be run at very high frequency. Please help me with i2(t).

Comment: What values are the primary inductance and the mutual coupling in your simulation? The graphs suggest an "ideal transformer" not a real one.

Comment: I took 1 H each case for simulation

Comment: I don't have coupled inductor in my simulation software hence I tried using 1:1 ideal transformer

Comment: Why have you used a 60Hz AC signal when the question clearly shows a DC supply?

Comment: Please help me with i1(t) and i2(t). If source is dc then what will be i2(t)? Because in steady state, i1 should be 10A.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on something similar but different.
[Can you see why R/Lin= 2ms ?](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzDMICMZICYaoOybmAHKgGwCcxmIALAspaiAKwCmAtIogFABKShIxviXhTzhRFCDQhTI9dgHcQhCnwEVl-cOwBOSNSt3LEqERPYBzHkmOXBUzQBVLGpfolIkKRMVQV69Ynj0mH7%209CDMxJABZIRgmBSE9GCoiHBhKKTE5gZWIoh6tqKo8oqG1vllJuziCKwF1qwC3qJgAPpKrW1U9HCtyK2o9JCEnQOjcNVg1Ji8cHS46rwQqO0UrZit3Wv9nqOIfbGT0wLWC0jNy6uj3b39RpB4oysrEzXhFSBz77waUlcbWz6bV2bX2tnYQA)  when Lp=1 , R=1

[image]

[image]

Your AC simulation lacks some spec so must be different from your expectations.  What is Zin(f)?